# Can i define a global handler that I can use with my scripts?

Tags: applescript

I write a lot of AppleScripts and I organized my codes by using library scripts. Is there a simple way to define a common handler that I can invoke from my scripts?

For example, I create a library with a handler:

Script Libraries/logger.scpt

```
to info(message)
  log(message)
end info
```

Then on my client scripts, I would do:

```
set logger to script "logger"
logger's info("Hello world")
```

Is it possible, how do I make it so that I can simply write the invocation as:

```
info("Greetings")
```

I want to omit the target and just call the handler directly from the client scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement an AppleScript Library with Terminology - i.e. add a dictionary to the library script.

There's a ton of information on this site http://macosxautomation.com and specifically on this and subsequent pages https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/libraries/terminology.html

Comment: I followed the video in the link you posted and I got it working, thank you so much!